# Wolfram Script as a Scheduled Task on Windows Server

Tags: export, pdf-format, windows, version-11, scripting

I have a wolfram script file (.wl) that processes a csv file and generates a PDF output.  I have written a PowerShell Script which checks for new input data files and runs the wolfram script file over them using the following command line:

> wolfram -script my_script_file.wl

This works fine when the process is run by a logged in user.  When it is run on a server executed by a Windows Scheduled Task, I encounter problems exporting the pdf.  The following error appears:

> Export::fmterr: Invalid PDF format.

I've tried to research this issue.  It seems that the part of Mathematica that generates the PDF export isn't available when run using a service account in a Windows Scheduled task.

Is there any way to get around this?  Has anyone encountered a similar issue?  Would using one of the other exe's to launch the script help?  wolframscript.exe, MathKernel.exe, etc?

Thanks for your time and assistance!

Comment: I haven't tried this...  But you probably would need to leave a user logged into the server, with the task set to use that user, and make sure "Run only when the user is logged on" is checked.

Comment: I have a feeling that would work, but unfortunately I don't have enough control over the server to ensure that a specific user account is always logged in.

Comment: Hopefully at some point that will no longer be a requirement...  But I cannot make any promises right now.

Comment: the usual cure for that is to wrap `UsingFrontEnd` around the code that needs frontend functionality. I don't know whether that would work in your case, though. But I think it would certainly be worth trying...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll give it a try and post back here what happens.

Comment: I tried wrapping `UsingFrontEnd` around the code, I get the same error.  There must be some resources or permissions on the Windows Server that are only available when the user is logged in.  I watch the task manager from a different account while the process is running, both the Wolfram Script Kernel and the full Mathematica app seem to launch.  I can get the process to generate the PDF using calls to the wolfram cloud instead of the local Export, but not sure if my production server environment will have the necessary access to the internet to do this.  Still researching, will post more soon

Comment: My client's server is not allowed internet access, otherwise using the wolfram cloud would be an excellent solution for getting exported output by a wolfram script run as a scheduled task.  Now investigating the possibility of porting the section that generates the document in to R Markdown as I believe it doesn't have the same limitations.